# App script equivalent to drag formula in spreadsheets for text

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

If I enter let's say "order001" in a spreadsheet cell and drag down it will repeat as "order002" , "order003" etc. Is there a way to do it in app script. I know we can use getFormulaR1C1 and setFormualR1C1 but that works only for Math or Macros. Is there a way to do this for text as said above.

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts. Reference [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understood your question. If I'm right, you should use a for loop padding the index with leading zeros.

```
function generateOrderNames() {
  var orderName = 'order';
  var from = 0;
  var to = 100;
  var orders = [];
  for (var i=from;i<to;i++) {
    var order = orderName + i.toString().lpad("0",+ 3);
    orders.push(order);  
  }
  Logger.log(orders); // Outputs [order000, order001, order002, order003, order004...order100]
}

String.prototype.lpad = function(padString, length) {
  var str = this;
  while (str.length < length)
    str = padString + str;
  return str;
}
```

Comment: Hey this solves the problem but I figured out an alternative way. In spreadsheet we can set number format to a range using setNumberFormat function. If I pass the value 1 and format it as "order000", the output will be "order001". Same works for 2, 3 ... etc.